# I am trying to use the Chartjs-plugin-watermark but it is not working

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, src, watermark

I've been trying to use the watermark plugin for charts.js. I have successfully downloaded the plugin and uploaded it to Github and created an online version of this file, viewable at: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AjaniSt/chartjs-plugin-watermark/chartjs-plugin-watermark.js. However, **the plugin is not working.** I have tried using a local file instead, putting the "watermark" data in and out of the "plugin" data, and trying the HTML online. However, none have worked. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated. My HTML file is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AjaniSt/chartjs-plugin-watermark/chartjs-plugin-watermark.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="ready()">
<canvas id="myChart" width="250" height="200"></canvas>
<script>

  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

  var imageNew = new Image()
  imageNew.src = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hi-hello-banner-speech-bubble-260nw-1505210795.jpg'
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [1880,
1881,
1882,
1883,
1884,
1885,
1886
],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Temperature Anomaly',
        data: [-0.16,
-0.08,
-0.1,
-0.17,
-0.28,
-0.33,
-0.31
],
fill: true,
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(10, 168, 196, 0.2)',
          'rgba(102, 96, 151, 0.2)',
          'rgba(57, 87, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(233, 182, 233, 0.2)',
          'rgba(108, 213, 207, 0.2)',
          'rgba(125, 178, 230, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(10, 168, 196, 1)',
          'rgba(102, 96, 151, 1)',
          'rgba(57, 87, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(233, 182, 233, 1)',
          'rgba(108, 213, 207, 1)',
          'rgba(125, 178, 230, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
pointRadius: 3,
pointHitRadius: 8
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
             callback: function(value, index, values) {
               return value + '°C';
             }
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Test'
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 15
            }
          }]
      },
      plugins:{
        legend: {display: false},
        watermark: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,

            height: 50,
            width: 50,

            alignX: "top",
            alignY: "left",
            alignToChartArea: true,

            position: "front",

            opacity: 1,

            image: imageNew,
        },
      },
      onClick: handleClick
    }
  });

  window.onmessage = function(event){

    if (event.data && Array.isArray(event.data)) {
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = event.data;
      myChart.update();
    }
    else {
      console.log("HTML Code Element received a generic message:");
      console.log(event.data);
    }
  };

  function handleClick(e){
    var activeBars = myChart.getElementAtEvent(e);

    var value = myChart.config.data.datasets[activeBars[0]._datasetIndex].data[activeBars[0]._index];
    var label = activeBars[0]._model.label;

    window.parent.postMessage({
      "type":"click",
      "label":label,
      "value":value
    } , "*");
  }

  function ready(){
    window.parent.postMessage({"type":"ready"}, "*");
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found a workaround but would still love to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What looks like the main reason that it's not working is because this plugin was written for V2 and you are using V3, the way you register plugins has changed so you need to change this line which can be found at the bottom of the file: `Chart.pluginService.register(watermarkPlugin);` to this: `Chart.register(watermarkPlugin)`

Comment: Thank you @LeeLenalee! I'm sure that was part of the problem. However, for some reason it is still not working. I have tried both with just defining the "image" property of the plugin as a source string, and as a `new Image()` with .src property. Here is the new hosting I'm using for the JS file, in case you are able/feel the need to take a look at it again: https://ajanist.github.io/kidsfightclimatechange/chartjs-plugin-watermark.js. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Thought that since you had a workaround the rest of the plugin worked but guess you will need to rewrite bigger parts of the plugin to make it v3 since there are some breaking changes in v3

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted, [`chartjs-plugin-watermark` 2.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-watermark/v/2.0.0) has been released and supports Chart.js 3 and 4. Additionally, the `watermark` config should be moved from `options.plugins.watermark` to just `options.watermark`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlbinoDrought/chartjs-plugin-watermark/chartjs-plugin-watermark.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="ready()">
<canvas id="myChart" width="250" height="200"></canvas>
<script>

  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

  var imageNew = new Image()
  imageNew.src = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hi-hello-banner-speech-bubble-260nw-1505210795.jpg'
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [1880,
1881,
1882,
1883,
1884,
1885,
1886
],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Temperature Anomaly',
        data: [-0.16,
-0.08,
-0.1,
-0.17,
-0.28,
-0.33,
-0.31
],
fill: true,
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(10, 168, 196, 0.2)',
          'rgba(102, 96, 151, 0.2)',
          'rgba(57, 87, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(233, 182, 233, 0.2)',
          'rgba(108, 213, 207, 0.2)',
          'rgba(125, 178, 230, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(10, 168, 196, 1)',
          'rgba(102, 96, 151, 1)',
          'rgba(57, 87, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(233, 182, 233, 1)',
          'rgba(108, 213, 207, 1)',
          'rgba(125, 178, 230, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
pointRadius: 3,
pointHitRadius: 8
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
             callback: function(value, index, values) {
               return value + '°C';
             }
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Test'
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 15
            }
          }]
      },
      plugins:{
        legend: {display: false},
      },
      watermark: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0,

          height: 50,
          width: 50,

          alignX: "top",
          alignY: "left",
          alignToChartArea: true,

          position: "front",

          opacity: 1,

          image: imageNew,
      },
      onClick: handleClick
    }
  });

  window.onmessage = function(event){

    if (event.data && Array.isArray(event.data)) {
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = event.data;
      myChart.update();
    }
    else {
      console.log("HTML Code Element received a generic message:");
      console.log(event.data);
    }
  };

  function handleClick(e){
    var activeBars = myChart.getElementAtEvent(e);

    var value = myChart.config.data.datasets[activeBars[0]._datasetIndex].data[activeBars[0]._index];
    var label = activeBars[0]._model.label;

    window.parent.postMessage({
      "type":"click",
      "label":label,
      "value":value
    } , "*");
  }

  function ready(){
    window.parent.postMessage({"type":"ready"}, "*");
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```